# Lighttpd Clean URL's and removing everything after FQDN?

Tags: regex, lighttpd, clean-urls

so i have figured out the regex to achieve this i just don't know how to make it work with lighttpd.

regex that works for me in other places

`(\/admin.*$)|(\/pihole.*$)`

should remove everything after the 3rd `/` in these 2 URL's

`https://pi.hole/admin/index.html`

`https://pi.hole/pihole/index.html`

there are no other sub directories in the root of the web server.

what i'd like to be left with is just a simple `https://pi.hole` URL in the address bar of the web browser.

Comment: Please clarify your question with more details and perhaps an example.  If you want `https://pi.hole/` to go to the admin page, use mod_rewrite.  If you want `https://pi.hole/admin/*` to redirect the browser to `https://pi.hole/`, use mod_redirect.  If you want `https://pi.hole/admin/` to display the index.html under that location, use mod_indexfile.

Comment: You might also try what should be obvious: use a search engine for the terms "clean urls lighttpd" and see the examples using lighttpd mod_rewrite.